# how to add swipe left and on image click drawer Android

Tags: android, swipe, drawer

i want to add Drawer to my app like i i draw in this pic.

is there any easy way to do so ?

i am not using material UI. started from empty acitivity

is there any way to do so ?

Check Image

[illustration of Drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sitDD.jpg)

Comment: Why don't we start with Googling: " Android navigation drawer"

Comment: http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/08/android-navigation-drawer-view.html check this tutorial

Comment: @James_Parsons i did googled it for 2,3 days before posting here tried most of tutorials it didn't worked for me that's why posted such question

Comment: Thanks a lot @shanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DrawerLayout` in the v4 support library. First, add the following dependency to you gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
```

Then, in the activity, you wish to have the drawer, replace the root view with `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`. The root should contain to child views, the first will be the main Activity, the second child will be the navigation drawer.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Main Activity Content -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Now, assuming that you understand how to set up `ListView`s, you should be able to set the `ListView` up and swipe to open.

To add the icon for opening up, you have to set up an `ActionBarDrawerToggle` in your activity, to do that would look something like this (remember to use the support library `ActionBarDrawerToggle`:

```
DrawerLayout layout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, layout, "Open Drawer", "Close Drawer") {
    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
        super.onDrawerClosed(view);
    }

    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
    }
}

// Set the toggle.
layout.setDrawerListener(toggle);
```

Then in your `onOptionsItemSelected`:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     if (toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
         return true;
     }
}
```

Now the icon should open the drawer.

The Android docs has a great tutorial for more information at: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: Thanks a lot friend :D